# Declaration in scope errors using execvp

Tags: c, shell

I am writing a C program that receives an input written by the user in console (Linux), creates a vector with the arguments received and executes them using a child Shell. I am getting all this errors/warnings while trying to compile it.
Probably it has something to do with the child Shell creation, but I am not sure. 
What's wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char *argVector[])
{
    char command[100];
    int status, pid;

    while (1)
    {   
        GetCommand( command );
        if(strcmp(command, "quit\n") == 0) break;
        if ( ( pid = fork() ) < 0 )
        {
            printf("%s\n", "Erro ao realizar fork");
            break;
        }       
        if( pid == 0 )
        {
            makeArgVector(command,argVector);
            if(execvp(argvector[0],argVector) < 0 ) 
            {
                printf("Erro ao executar comando");
                break;
            }
        }else
            wait(&status);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Once I try to compile the program this error/warning pops up:

```
wait(&status) was not declared in this scope.
```

Comment: Which headers did you include?  Why didn't the list include `<sys/wait.h>`?

Comment: please post code, so we can compile it and then help you correct the syntax errors.  The currently posted code is missing some things, like the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: regarding; `if(execvp(argvector[0],argVector) < 0 ) 
            {
                printf("Erro ao executar comando");
                break;
            }`  1) error message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) none of the `exec*()` functions return unless it failed to start the other process. So all that is needed is:  `execvp(argvector[0],argVector);  perror( "execvp failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: Note that your `makeArgVector()` is given only as much space to work with as there were arguments to your `main()` program (command line arguments).  This is fragile, at best, especially as you don't tell `makeArgVector()` how much space it has to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait() is declared in wait.h file. so we have to include this header as below so that compiler get the declaration from the header file.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
```